# Nontrivial group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose $G$ is a non-trivial group. Also, $\forall H \subset G, $ where $H$ is a subgroup we have that $H=\{e\}$ or $H=G$. I want to prove that G is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for some prime $p$.

I think I am on the right track. I want to show that $\phi:G\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_p$ is an isomorphism. This requires $ker\phi = \{e\}$. But, I already have that $H=\{e\}$, so that part is done(?).

Also, I know $\exists g \in G$ s.t. $g\neq e$ since $|G|>1$. I know that since $|\mathbb{Z}_p|=p$ for some prime $p$, $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a cyclic group $<a>$ generated by $a$ for some $a\in \mathbb{Z}_p$. I do not know where to go from here to complete the proof, or if these facts should even be used.

Comment: What would be $\phi$??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you know that $G$ is cyclic since $\langle g\rangle=G$ for any $e\neq g\in G$. Fix such a $g\in G$, and examine the map $f:\mathbb Z\to G$ by $n\mapsto g^n$. Then $G\cong \mathbb Z/\ker f$. Can you conclude?

Addendum: why isn't $|G|$ composite? Well we showed it's cyclic, so let $g$ generate $G$ as above. Let $|G|=pq$ with $(p,q)=1$, $p,q\neq 1$. Then $g^p$ has order $q$ in $G$, so $\langle g^p\rangle\subsetneq G$ is a nontrivial subgroup of order $q$.

Comment: So, for some $g\in G$, $|g|=p$. Also, the inverse of an isomorphism is also an isomorphism. So, $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: If you prove (as in T. Bongers' answer) that $|G|=p$, then you know that $\ker f=p\mathbb Z$ so that $|\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z|=p$ and the orders work out. That oughta do it for you.

Comment: I suppose the confusing part is proving that $|G|=p$. Is it because $|H|=1$ or $|H|=|G|$, which implies that G doesn't have composite order?

Comment: If it doesn't notify you when I add something, see above.

Answer (score 1):

You've got the right idea: If $G$ is a non-trivial group, then choose any $g \in G, g \ne e$.  Let $H = \langle g \rangle$ be the cyclic subgroup generated by $g$. Now convince yourself

- $g$ cannot have composite order; let $|g| = p$.
- $G = H$
- $\langle g \rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}_p$